# Custom template for password protected page

Tags: wp-query, loop, query-posts, password

I have a password-protected page, for whom I'd like to use a custom template to query posts from a specific category. How can I achieve that query_posts should work only after users submit the password of the page?
I'm trying with this but doesn't work (page only displays header and footer)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: xxxx
*/
?>

        <?php get_header(); ?>
            <?php if ( post_password_required() ) : ?>
            <?php query_posts('cat=9'); ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1 style="padding-top:0;margin-top:-5px" class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                <div class="entry-content" style="padding:0"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                                        <div class="entry-meta">
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    </div>


            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Solved with this code :)
http://pastebin.com/HkH9UyBF

Comment: So the answer stays hidden on an external site? Shall I close the question, or will you add an answer here?

Comment: Uhm, I don't have enough rep to answer my questions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separate the queries for the current page and the query for all posts in a category.
Untested example:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: xxxx
*/
?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( post_password_required() ) :
    $args = array(
        'cat' => 9,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h1 style="padding-top:0;margin-top:-5px" class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </a>
        <div class="entry-content" style="padding:0"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I think this is wrong : the code inside `if ( post_password_required() )` block will be executed only if the user is *not* authenticated.

Comment: post_password_required() returns true if post requires password and correct password has been provided. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_password_required

Comment: I'm sorry, but you should read the doc twice : `return value : False if a password is not required or the correct password cookie is present, true otherwise.` It means that if the user is authenticated (password has been provided before and the auth cookie is present) it will return **false**. I admit that the codex formulation is confusing, but the behavior is the expected one. If you have already provided the password, it is not required anymore!

Comment: Another formulation would be : `return value : true if a password is required and has not been verified, false otherwise`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good MultiformeIngegno, but you should use the WP template tag `get_the_password_form()` instead of harcoding the password form, like shown in [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Add_the_Password_Form_to_the_Excerpt) :

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: xxxx
*/
?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
        <?php if ( post_password_required() ) : 

            // ask for the password
            echo get_the_password_form(); 
        else: 

            // authenticated user, display the content
        ?>
        <?php query_posts('cat=9'); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h1 style="padding-top:0;margin-top:-5px" class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
            <div class="entry-content" style="padding:0"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                                    <div class="entry-meta">
                <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                </div>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>


    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```